# How to optimize application to display more markers effectively on google map in flutter?

Tags: performance, google-maps, flutter, optimization, google-maps-api-3

Im working on a project, in this project I have to display markers on the map from database. In database i have around 6000+ customers data, and I want to display there information on maps using there latitude and longitude. Problem is when there is record of only 5-10 customers, app doesn't slow down, but when i display thousands of markers on the map, app starts lagging. is there any better way to solve this problem?

**code for displaying markers on map**

```
_onMapCreated() async {
    // print(customerInfo);
    for (var item in ud.customerInfo) {
      if (item['customer_latitude'] == "" && item['customer_longitude'] == "") {
        continue;
      } else {
        final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId((markers.length + 1).toString());
        LatLng markerPos = LatLng(double.parse(item['customer_latitude']),
            double.parse(item['customer_longitude']));
        final Marker marker = Marker(
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
              title: item['customer_name'],
              snippet: item['customer_desc'],
            ),
            // onTap: () => _onMarkerTapped(markerId),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                item['customer_status'] == 'red'
                    ? BitmapDescriptor.hueRed
                    : item['customer_status'] == 'yellow'
                        ? BitmapDescriptor.hueYellow
                        : BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
            markerId: markerId,
            consumeTapEvents: true,
            position: markerPos,
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return CustomerDetail(
                          item['customer_id'],
                          item['customer_name'],
                          item['customer_email'],
                          item['customer_desc'],
                          item['customer_phone'],
                          item['customer_status']);
                    },
                    fullscreenDialog: true,
                  ));
            });
        _markers = null;
        markers[markerId] = marker;
      }
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

one more point, the data is already fetched from database and stored in a list, so during loop it is just getting data from the list and rendering it on the google maps.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering thousand of markers in google map is not optimized yet in flutter, I think you need to do clustering to solve this, things like this: [clustering](https://coletiv.com/blog/how-to-cluster-markers-on-google-maps-using-flutter/)